# How can I implement a dynamic selection?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am making a strategy game AI. Specifically, I'm using BWMirror java library to make Starcraft: BroodWar zerg AI.

I came accross a problem with unit management. Player has some units in his disposition, let's say it's `List<Unit>` with such contents:

```
Offset Name     Position
0.     Drone    [Worker]
1.     Drone    [Worker]
2.     Zergling [Fighter]
3.     Hatchery [Building]
4.     Drone    [Worker]
5.     Larva    [Passive]
```

Some functions obviously only work with unit subsets. I have implemented a method that selects subset from the main list and returns it as new list. For workers, I'd get:

```
Offset Name     Position
0.     Drone    [Worker]
1.     Drone    [Worker]
2.     Drone    [Worker]
```

Now if one of these workers is removed from the original list (eg. because it dies), it will persist in this sub-list. There are 2 possible solutions and I don't like either:

1. Generate the selection list every time when needed.
2. Assign some event callbacks to remove items in all lists they are present in.

My questions is: Is there any kind of data storage that would let me make sub-selections but allow me to keep the data synchronized?

This means I'd have two `Iterable` objects and one would contain all units, other would contain workers. And removing worker from all units would also make it disappear from workers, without any callback.

Comment: I just recalled that I allways wondered how do DOMCollections in JavaScript work. Maybe there's the answer to my question.

Comment: This might work for you? http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter

Comment: Do you need to be able to get items in the worker list quickly by index? If yes, then it's much more tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only have the 2 options you listed, and of the two, I think your first option makes the most sense.

Lazily generating the list only when you needed it would save a lot of cycles.  One stim packed up Marine (such as yourself) , might kill a huge number of zerglings,  you really don't want to be sending messages for every zergling that dies.  It would be much better to just see what you have left when you need them.

Comment: Also implementing option `2.` turned to be painful and not very flexible.